# Unable to scrape from a page that requires login

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have to scrape data from a website, that requires login.

This is the current code I am using, but I am not getting the logged in page's HTML.

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with Session() as s:
    site = s.get("https://www.valueresearchonline.com/membership/getin.asp?ref=%2Fport_v1%2Fdefault%2Easp%3Fselv%3D8%26poid%3D1443091")
    bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
    token = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"ref"})["value"]
    login_data = {"username":"<username>","password":"<password>","ref":token}
    p = s.post("https://www.valueresearchonline.com/membership/getin.asp?ref=%2Fport_v1%2Fdefault%2Easp%3Fselv%3D8%26poid%3D1443091",login_data)
    print(p.text)
```

The HTML I am getting is the same as the one as before logging in. Also, I am not sure whether the token part was required for this site, so I have tried both by once using it and once not using it, but I both cases the result was the same as I explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more parameter in the

`p = s.post("https://www.valueresearchonline.com/membership/getin.asp?ref=%2Fport_v1%2Fdefault%2Easp%3Fselv%3D8%26poid%3D1443091",login_data)`

as `allow_redirects=True` and change the URL to `https://www.valueresearchonline.com/registration/loginprocess.asp`:

```
p = s.post("p = s.post("https://www.valueresearchonline.com/registration/loginprocess.asp", data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)", data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
```

Check if this works for you.

Comment: The post request should be sent to this URL.
`p = s.post("https://www.valueresearchonline.com/registration/loginprocess.asp", data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)`

Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Put your email and password within the value of `payload['username']` and `payload['password']` and I suppose it will log you in.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.valueresearchonline.com/membership/getin.asp"
post_url = "https://www.valueresearchonline.com/registration/loginprocess.asp"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    site = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site.text, "lxml")
    payload = {item['name']:item.get('value','') for item in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['username'] = 'your email'
    payload['password'] = 'your password'
    p = s.post(post_url,data=payload)
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: This method worked. But why the line                                                                   
    payload = {item['name']:item.get('value','') for item in soup.select('input[name]')}

Comment: Use this command `print(payload)` to understand why that very line has been used.